# play/pause video onclick firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I want **videos** to **play/pause** when you `click` on them. Firefox has this behaviour by default. Chrome does not. The simple solution I came up with was setting a click event with jQuery.

```
var video = $('#myVideo');
var videoDomObj = video.get(0);
//click event for the video itself
video.on('click', function(e){
    //when video is clicked it should be paused when playing and vise versa
    if (videoDomObj.paused){
        videoDomObj.play();
    } else{
        videoDomObj.pause();
    }
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uamfjc1s/4/)**

This will work in IE and Chrome. However, this will result in a conflict in Firefox, since it will instantly call the default event afterwards and will not play the video at all. `e.preventDefault()` fixes this problem, but will break all the other controls in Firefox. While they still work, they will play/pause the video. Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: You are listen click event in the parent object. If you make click in the bottom border of the video, it works. Are you trying to listen the click in the videoDomObj and try to preventDefault inside it?

Comment: Just listening to events of the parent object will result in the same problem. I provided a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem. preventDefault() fixes the problem in firefox but breaks the other controls

Comment: @HoschNok Take a look at my answer, it functions for both browsers with preventDefault() and a parent object as the clickable element.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the raw code worked like a charm:

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.paused){
        this.play();
    } else{
        this.pause();
    }
}
```

The jQuery equivalent should be:

```
jQuery('#myVideo').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.paused){
        this.play();
    } else{
        this.pause();
    }
});
```

**But as you said that breaks the video controlls**, desired and simplest solution for this could be selecting a parent element (or **adding a container**, if required):

```
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
video.parentElement.onclick = function(e) {
    if (video.paused){
        video.play();
    } else{
        video.pause();
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
var $video = jQuery('#myVideo'), video = $video.get(0);
$video.parent().on('click', function(e) {
    if (video.paused){
        video.play();
    } else{
        video.pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code results in exactly the same problem. All controls will pause/play the video in firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/uamfjc1s/6/

Comment: yeah, sorry, that was an unnecessary e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found was to detect the browser for this special case, since the problem only occurs in firefox and it has this feature by default anyway.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uamfjc1s/9/)**

```js
//jQuery video element
var video = $('#myVideo');
//DOM element for HTML5 media events
var videoDomObj = video.get(0);
//detect if firefox
var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

//only bind click event if not firefox to prevent broken controls - firefox pauses/plays videos on click by default anyway
if (!is_firefox){
    video.on('click', function(e){
        //when video is clicked it should be paused when playing and vise versa
        if (videoDomObj.paused){
            videoDomObj.play();
        } else{
            videoDomObj.pause();
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```